# How to use Javascript array.find() with two conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check if any object in an array of objects has a `type: a` AND if another has a `type: b`

I initially did this:

`const myObjects = objs.filter(attr => attr.type === 'a' || attr.type === 'b');`

But the code review complained that `filter` will keep going through the entire array, when we just need to know if any single object meets either criteria.

I wanted to use `array.find()` but this only works for a single condition.

Is there anyway to do this without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 3):

you can pass two condition as given below

```
[7,5,11,6,3,19].find(attr => {
    return (attr > 100 || attr %2===0);
});
6

[7,5,102,6,3,19].find(attr => {
    return (attr > 100 || attr %2===0);
});
102
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated answer:

It's not possible to shortcircuit js's builtin functions that does what you want, so you will have to use some kind of loop:

```js
let a;
let b;
for (const elm of objs) {
  if (!a && elm === 'a') {
    a = elm;
  }
  if (!b && elm === 'b') {
    b = elm;
  }
  const done = a && b;
  if (done) break;
}
```

Also you should consider if you can record `a` and `b` when producing the array if that's possible.

---

#### Oiginal answer:

`find` works just like `filter` where it takes a predicate, returns the first element that the predicate returns `true`.

If I understood your question correctly, you can just replace the `filter` with `find` and it will return at the first occurance:

```js
const myObject = objs.find(attr => attr.type === 'a' || attr.type === 'b');
```

Also notice your provided snippet is wrong for what you described: `filter` returns an array but you only wanted one element. so you should add `[0]` to the filter expression if you want to use it.

Comment: Won't this stop as soon as it finds an element that has a? meaning it will never look for b if it has found a

Comment: @codemon Can you phrase your problem more clearly then? Based on your description I assumed you want the first 'a' or 'b'. Or do you want the first 'a' and the first 'b'?

Comment: I want the first 'a' or the first 'b' or both if both exist.

Comment: @codemon At that point I think the answer is "no": You will have to write a for loop then, and in my opinion well-written for loops are very readable. See edited answer for example.